# require.resolve() works. Why doesn't module.parent.require.resolve()?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to find the file of included modules.  From the main module, `require.resolve('module')` happily returns me the value of the  `main` key from the module's package.json.

However, I would like to do this from a module that's been included via npm.  If I simply call `require.resolve('module')`, it looks in the node_modules for this module, whereas I need to resolve it from the point of view of the running package.

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), `require` is actually `module.require` and `module.parent` returns the module that first required this one.  Why then does `module.parent.require.resolve('module')` not work?  I get ana
 error:

```
TypeError: module.parent.require.resolve is not a function
```

Oddly though, `console.log module.parent.require.toString()` returns

```
function (path) {
  assert(path, 'missing path');
  assert(typeof path === 'string', 'path must be a string');
  return Module._load(path, this, /* isMain */ false);
}
```

so it certainly looks like a function to me.

Anyone know what's going on?  I've also tried `require.main.require.resolve()` and that does a very similar thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `TypeError: module.parent.require.resolve is not a function`
>
> Oddly though, `console.log module.parent.require.toString()` returns ...

`module.parent.require` is a function, `module.parent.require.resolve` is not.

#### Why is `resolve()` not a function?

It appears `require()` and `module.require()` are not the same:

```
console.log(require === module.require); // false
```

For the curious:

`console.log(module.require.toString())`

```
function (path) {
  assert(path, 'missing path');
  assert(typeof path === 'string', 'path must be a string');
  return Module._load(path, this, /* isMain */ false);
}
```

`console.log(require.toString())`

```
function require(path) {
  try {
    exports.requireDepth += 1;
    return mod.require(path);
  } finally {
    exports.requireDepth -= 1;
  }
}
```

So `require()` calls `module.require()`, but is not the same thing.

#### What about `resolve()`?

We know `require.resolve` is a function:

`console.log(require.resolve.toString())`

```
function resolve(request) {
  return Module._resolveFilename(request, mod);
}
```

But `module.require.resolve` is not:

`console.log(module.require.resolve)`

```
undefined
```

So unfortunately `resolve()` is only available at `require.resolve()`, and not at `module.require.resolve()` (or `module.parent.require.resolve()` for that matter).

#### Solution?

Not a great solution, but you could try manually calling `Module._resolveFilename()` and passing in the parent module instead of the current module:

```
const Module = module.constructor;

const fileName = Module._resolveFilename('module', module.parent);
```

This solution isn't great because it relies on internal API functions that could possibly change in the future. It would be nice if [NodeJS](https://github.com/nodejs/node) would provide better documentation and APIs for module loading/resolving.

Comment: Brilliant.  This works like a dream, thanks.

But I agree, better documentation, especially of the difference between `require` and `module.require`, would be good.